# Need to retrieve and convert to an integer using SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to match the users ID (pk) on the 'users' table, with the users ID (fk) on the 'owners' table, but it seems to not be working.

But it gives me and error on the dono (onwer) saying that I need to convert it.

```
 protected void confirmarButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int n = 0;

        if (primeiroNome.Text != "" & nomeDoMeio.Text != "" && sobrenome.Text != "" && dataDeNascimento.Text != "" && enderecoPostal1.Text != "" && cidade.Text != "" && email.Text != "" && username.Text != "" && password.Text != "" && confirmarPassword.Text != "")
        {
            if (password.Text == confirmarPassword.Text)
            {
                String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ClinicaAnimal"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
                {

                    n = userIdNumber();


                    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("Insert into Users ([Username], [Password],[Tipo de User])Values('" + username.Text + "','" + Encrypt(password.Text.Trim()) + "','" + "Dono" + "')", con);
                   // cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Encrypt(password.Text.Trim()));
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Dono ([Primeiro Nome], [Nome do Meio], [Sobrenome], [Data de Nascimento], [Endereço Postal1], [Endereço Postal2], [Cidade], [Email], [UserID])Values('" + primeiroNome.Text + "','" + nomeDoMeio.Text + "','" + sobrenome.Text + "','" + dataDeNascimento.Text + "','" + enderecoPostal1.Text + " ','" + enderecoPostal2.Text + " ','" + cidade.Text + " ','" + email.Text + "','"+ "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()" +"')", con);


                    con.Open();

                    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                    Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx");
                }
            }
            else
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: This is the same problem stated here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48723092/match-the-foreign-key-with-the-primary-key-in-sql-server-asp-net?noredirect=1#comment84445616_48723092 Why do you post again the same code? Where is instead your attempt to use the SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY? Where is your attempt to convert the result of ExecuteScalar?

Comment: I'm a colleague of that guy @Steve, we both have the same code for our project and he couldn't figure it out

Comment: Then re-read carefully my comments there. (And pay attention to semicolons also)

Comment: Okay, I've done that but it gave me this error "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()' to data type int.'
"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, you can combine both `cmd` and `cmd 2` sql statements together.

Also use `SqlParameters` instead of concatinating strings in Sql to prevent **SqlInjection**

Code could be like following:

```
var query = "Insert into Users ([Username], [Password],[Tipo de User])Values('" + username.Text + "','" + Encrypt(password.Text.Trim()) + "','Dono')";

query += @"Declare @value as int
          Select @value = Scope_Identity() ";

query += "Insert into Dono ([Primeiro Nome], [Nome do Meio], [Sobrenome], [Data de Nascimento], [Endereço Postal1], [Endereço Postal2], [Cidade], [Email], [UserID])Values('" + primeiroNome.Text + "','" + nomeDoMeio.Text + "','" + sobrenome.Text + "','" + dataDeNascimento.Text + "','" + enderecoPostal1.Text + " ','" + enderecoPostal2.Text + " ','" + cidade.Text + " ','" + email.Text + "',@value) ";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
//Add required SqlParameters to cmd here

 con.Open();

 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

**Edit**

Removed `scope_identity` from sql and used inline sql variable, and removed old suggestion of `ExecuteScalar`.

Comment: Thanks for that info, but I can't seem to get the same value on the userID fk that I've got in the other table

Comment: Since now you will be executing both sql together and fetching scope_identity in same sql, you should get the correct user id. I hope UserId is also set to Identity in Users table. See modified Sql in my answer. @user9236225

Comment: Thank you so much mate! That fixed it! More knowledge acquired hehe